# Neat redistribution of association values

Tags: list-manipulation, expression-manipulation, associations

Given an original association:

```
original = <|  "a" -> {a1, a2},  "b" -> {b1, b2},  "c" -> {c1, c2}  |>
```

and a set of redistribution rules e.g.

```
distribution = <|
  "a" -> <|"A" -> .5, "B" -> .5|>,
  "b" -> <|"C" -> 1|>,
  "c" -> <|"C" -> 1|>
|>
```

How to generate

```
<| 
  "A" -> .5{ a1 , a2},
  "B" -> .5{ a1, a2},
  "C" -> {b1, b2} + {c1, c2}
|>
```

Original association and the final result are strict but `distribution` form can be changed to something that work better with your solution.

I tried

```
distribution //
  KeyValueMap[ Module[{mark}, #2 mark /. mark -> original[#]] &    ]  // 
  Merge[Total]

(*mark is there to thread nicely*)
```

Neat but it is not very readable.
Nested Table would be readable but not neat.

Is there something idiomatic and readable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can write it without the need for variable `mark` as follows.

```
Merge[ KeyValueMap[#1*#2 &, distribution], Total ] /. original
```

> <|"A" -> 0.5 {a1, a2}, "B" -> 0.5 {a1, a2}, "C" -> {b1, b2} + {c1, c2}|>

More so, the alternative solution provided by @Kuba using operator form is much more readable I believe.

```
ReplaceAll[original] @ Merge[Total] @ KeyValueMap[Times] @ distribution
```

> <|"A" -> 0.5 {a1, a2}, "B" -> 0.5 {a1, a2}, "C" -> {b1, b2} + {c1, c2}|>

Answer (score 3):

If I understood correctly the goal, then may be you can benefit from generalizing this a bit.

The following function will reverse your redistribution rules, taking two functions - combiner and reducer:

```
ClearAll[reverse]
reverse[assoc_Association?AssociationQ, reducer_, combiner_] := 
  Merge[
    Flatten @ Map[reverse[#, reducer]&, Normal @ assoc], 
    combiner
  ]

reverse[key_ -> value_Association?AssociationQ, reducer_]:=
  Map[
    reverse[key, #, reducer]&, 
    Normal @ value
  ]

reverse[key_, other_ -> weight_, reducer_]:= other -> reducer[key, weight]
```

Now, you get what you want with:

```
reverse[
  distribution,
  Times[#2, original[#1]] &, 
  Total
]

(* <|"A" -> {0.5 a1, 0.5 a2}, "B" -> {0.5 a1, 0.5 a2}, "C" -> {b1 + c1, b2 + c2}|> *)
```

The code is somewhat more verbose than in your solution, but I think it is also somewhat more understandable.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this answer is so much more concise than the implementation in the question. Far from it. I present it here mostly to hint at a different implementation for `distribution`, if such a reformulation makes sense in the context of the question.

Please consider redefining `distribution` to the definition below:

```
distribution2 = <|
  "A" -> <|"a" -> .5, "b" -> 0., "c" -> 0.|>,
  "B" -> <|"a" -> .5, "b" -> 0., "c" -> 0.|>,
  "C" -> <|"a" -> 0., "b" -> 1., "c" -> 1.|>
 |>;
```

Then, it's just a matter of '*applying*' the distribution in a sense:

```
Map[(KeyValueMap[#2 original[#1] &, #] &) /* Total, distribution2]
```

evaluates to

> ```
> <|"A" -> {0. + 0.5 a1, 0. + 0.5 a2}, 
>   "B" -> {0. + 0.5 a1, 0. + 0.5 a2}, 
>   "C" -> {0. + 1. b1 + 1. c1, 0. + 1. b2 + 1. c2}|>
> ```

You can add `Chop` if you need better looking results:

```
Map[(KeyValueMap[#2 original[#1] &, #] &) /* Total /* Chop, distribution2]
```

> ```
> <|"A" -> {0.5 a1, 0.5 a2}, 
>   "B" -> {0.5 a1, 0.5 a2}, 
>   "C" -> {1. b1 + 1. c1, 1. b2 + 1. c2}|>
> ```

Answer (score 2):

```
Merge[Total][Times @@@ Normal[distribution]] /. original
```

> <|"A" -> 0.5 {a1, a2}, "B" -> 0.5 {a1, a2},  "C" -> {b1, b2} + {c1, c2}|>

Also

```
Merge[Total][Keys[#] Values[#]]& @ distribution /. original
```

> <|"A" -> 0.5 {a1, a2}, "B" -> 0.5 {a1, a2},  "C" -> {b1, b2} + {c1, c2}|>